# Permission error when accessing AWS secrets manager from an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I have a Python program running on a linux EC2 instance, I am trying to get a value from secrets manager but I keep getting a permissions error

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetSecretValue operation: User: arn:aws:sts::user_id_here:assumed-role/AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSetup/somestring is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on resource: arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-2:xxx_my_secret
```

In my IAM settings the user is inside a group with Administrator access and then the user itself has the perimssion `SecretsManagerReadWrite`

What permissions do I need to change?

Comment: What do you mean by "the user"? It would appear that the script using an IAM Role that was assigned to the EC2 instance, not an IAM User. If you want to use IAM User credentials, you should run `aws configure` and store the credentials locally.

Comment: Do you have rights to access the KMS key encrypting the secret ?

Comment: By user I mean the user referenced in the error code by user_id_here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user who accesses the EC2 has different role from the machine itself.

The role and access of the machine to secrets manager are defined by either

- User Role (upon creation of EC2 in AWS Console), or
- ./aws/credentials and ./aws/configuration

In my code, I used boto.utils.get_instance_identity() to get the region. Then get the access_key and secret_key from boto3.Session().get_credentials().get_frozen_credentials()

You may also want to use botocore.credentials.RefreshableCredentials since the token from get_frozen_credentials() expires.

Comment: I had applied permissions to the wrong role, I found my EC2 instance in AWS console and added the permissions to its role from there